# Pesquisa de Arquivos em Tempo Real

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando fazer um programa que fornece o recurso de pesquisa de arquivos em tempo real.

À medida que o usuário for digitando o nome de um diretório na caixa de texto, o programa deve pesquisar e exibir na área de texto os nomes de todos os arquivos e subdiretórios que encontrar no diretório, cujo nome está na caixa de texto.

Eu consegui fazer com que ele liste as pastas do diretório `C:/`, mas as subpastas e arquivos ele não lista.

Segue o código:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class PesquisarArquivoGUI extends JFrame  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public PesquisarArquivoGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 410, 423);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDiretrio = new JLabel("Diret\u00F3rio:");
        lblDiretrio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblDiretrio.setBounds(10, 11, 64, 17);
        contentPane.add(lblDiretrio);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                File arquivo = new File("C:\\");

                File[] lista = arquivo.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                        return pathname.getName().contains(textField.getText());
                    }
                });

                for(File f : lista)
                    textArea.setText(f.getPath());
            }
        });


        textField.setBounds(73, 11, 311, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 43, 394, 341);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

de uma pesquisada sobre como funciona o `JFileChooser`

A implementação dele é bem simples ex:

```java
        JFileChooser fl = new JFileChooser();
        fl.setDialogTitle("Buscar arquivo"); //titulo do jDialog
        fl.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY); //aceita somente arquivos (pode ser usado outra constante do JFileChooser)
        int op = fl.showOpenDialog(null); //abre o jDialog
        if (op == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //se foi clicado em abrir
            //obtem o arquivo utilizando por exemplo File f = fl.getSelectedFile();
        }
```